# No such file or directory error when configuring aws on cygwin

Tags: amazon-web-services, cygwin

I downloaded Cygwin and Python version 2.5. Now I am about to set up an deep learning computer at aws (following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rjRfW4JM2I)

If i run pip install awscli I get this (which is good)

```
 $ pip install awscli 
 Requirement already satisfied: awscli in c:\users\marc\anaconda2    \lib\site-packages
 Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.9 in c:\users\marc\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from awscli)
 Requirement already satisfied: rsa<=3.5.0,>=3.1.2 in c:\users\marc\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from awscli)
 Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML<=3.12,>=3.10 in c:\users\marc\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from awscli)
 Requirement already satisfied: docutils>=0.10 in c:\users\marc\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from awscli)
Requirement already satisfied: botocore==1.4.92 in c:\users\marc\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from awscli)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama<=0.3.7,>=0.2.5 in c:\users\marc\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from awscli)
Requirement already satisfied: futures<4.0.0,>=2.2.0; python_version == "2.6" or python_version == "2.7" in c:\users\marc\anaconda2\lib\site- packages (from s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.9->awscli)
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1>=0.1.3 in c:\users\marc\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from rsa<=3.5.0,>=3.1.2->awscli)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in c:\users\marc\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from botocore==1.4.92->awscli)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in c:\users\marc\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from botocore==1.4.92->awscli)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\marc\anaconda2\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore==1.4.92->awscli)
```

However when I want to configure everything and type aws I get:

```
$ aws
C:\Users\Marc\Anaconda2\python.exe: can't open file '/cygdrive/c/Users/Marc/Anaconda2/Scripts/aws': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Comment: Mixing cygwin with non-cygwin Python may be difficult, including problems with file path syntax.

Comment: And case sensitivity

Comment: @tim18 could you please elobarate? I dont understand it

Comment: Windows versions of python, other than cygwin's own python, are likely to fail to parse cygwin/posix style paths.

Comment: Experiencing the exact same problem on Windows 10, cygwin 2.6.1, Anaconda 4.2.9, Python 2.7.12 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)

Comment: Experiencing the same problem. Any work around?

Comment: I also experienced the same problem -- running aws with an admin command prompt from the Script directory worked

Answer (score 6):

After a LOT of time spent on this, I found a solution that works.

The primary issue is that the cygwin didn't come with python installed, and doesn't know where to find the existing Windows Anaconda version on your machine. This can be verified by running which python from within cygwin - it couldn't find where python is saved. Note that this can be confusing because running pip install awscli likely doesn't throw an error message. Cygwin actually installs awscli in the Window's Anaconda installation of Python (I find this odd since we didn't run conda install awscli).

HOWEVER, rather than try to point cygwin to the already installed version of Anaconda python on your machine it will save you a ton of headache to just install a cygwin-specific instance of python.  The steps to do so are documented here: http://wiki.fast.ai/index.php/Awscli_in_cygwin)

1. `pip uninstall awscli`
2. `wget rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg`
3. `install apt-cyg /bin`
4. `apt-cyg install python`
5. `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`
6. `python get-pip.py`
7. `pip install awscli`

...Note, however, that the first command `pip uninstall awscli` "hung up" for me.  So just escape out of it using `quit()` and continue with the others in order.

You can check that everything worked if you run `which python` in cygwin and it points to the cygin version (i.e. /usr/bin/python , as opposed to:  /users/.../Anaconda2/).

Additionally, if you happen to be asking this in conjunction with watching the setup video for the fast.ai course (http://course.fast.ai/lessons/aws.html), then the next step is ***CRITICAL*** for Windows users: when you download all the shell scripts from Github setup folder (https://github.com/fastai/courses/tree/master/setup), Windows automatically adds CRLF line terminators!  Therefore, in cygwin, run the following commands to remove these line endings:

1. `apt-cyg install dos2unix`
2. `dos2unix setup_p2.sh`
3. `dos2unix setup_instance.sh`
4. then finally, `bash setup_p2.sh`

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 6):

I got on track with the answer by Ryan Chase (however I can't comment on his answer due to insufficient credit on stackoverflow)

after step 4: `apt-cyg install python`, 
`which python` would return the desired `usr/bin/python`.
However, running `python -i` from cygwin still opened up my local anaconda python instead of the cygwin python.

I ended up using this workflow:

1. `pip uninstall awscli`
2. `wget rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg`
3. `install apt-cyg /bin`
4. `apt-cyg install python`
5. `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py`
6. `/bin/python ~/get-pip.py`
7. `/bin/pip install awscli`
8. `/bin/aws`

etc. so each time, use `/bin/...` to force cygwin to use it's local version of the program. It's pretty cumbersome, maybe I'll look into better ways of getting cygwin to prefer it's own version of python over the anaconda version.

I also needed to change the setup files from windows to unix style, so:

1. `apt-cyg install dos2unix`
2. `dos2unix setup_p2.sh`
3. `dos2unix setup_instance.sh`
4. `then finally, bash setup_p2.sh`

Answer (score 2):

Normal simple pip and awscli install

```
$curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py"
$python get-pip.py
$pip install awscli --upgrade
.
.
.
$aws dms help
C:\python35\python.exe: can't open file '/cygdrive/c/Python35/Scripts/aws': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

D'oh! The path in the error indicates the windows python path has precedence over desired the cygwin python path in my execution path

```
$echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/Python35/Scripts:/cygdrive/c/Python35:/cygdrive/c/OBASE/11gR2x32/bin:/cygdrive/c/OBASE/11gR2x64/bin:/cygdrive/c/OBASE12/12cR1x64/bin:/cygdrive/c/OBASE12/12cR1x32/bin:/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/IBM/WebSphere MQ/Java/lib:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/IBM/WebSphere MQ/bin64:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/IBM/WebSphere MQ/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/IBM/WebSphere MQ/tools/c/samples/bin:/cygdrive/c/windows/system32/11g:/cygdrive/c/windows/system32/12c:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Verint/Playback:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Amazon/AWSCLI:/cygdrive/c/Users/r608182/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/usr/lib/lapack:/cygdrive/c/Program/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144/:wq/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_144//bin
```

I removed two suspect execution path culprits from my execution path 
[edit foo and remove /cygdrive/c/Python35/Scripts and /cygdrive/c/Python35 and save foo]

```
$echo $PATH > foo
$vi foo
```

[reset path with culprit entries removed]

```
$export PATH=`cat foo`
```

and simple as that all is right with the world again

```
$ aws dms help

dms
^^^


Description
***********

AWS Database Migration Service (AWS DMS) can migrate your data...
```

You want to put this execution path fix into your .bashrc so it's permanent

Answer (score 1):

Try this (if for example on your machine you have installed anacond2 at c:\anaconda2)

```
echo "PATH=\$PATH:/cygdrive/c/anaconda2" >> .bash_profile
echo "PATH=\$PATH:/cygdrive/c/anaconda2/Scripts" >> .bash_profile
source .bash_profile
```

More info available at https://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/set-up-python-windows/#installing-cygwin

Comment: My Anaconda is installed here: C:\Users\Marc\Anaconda2. However also when I try to run it with this path I still get the error: C:\Users\Marc\Anaconda2\python.exe: can't open file '/cygdrive/c/Users/Marc/Anaconda2/Scripts/aws': [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Any more thoughts?

Comment: try running aws in the anaconda scripts directory....so cd /cygdrive/c/users\Marc\Anaconda2\Scripts and then run python aws

Comment: @maheshmadhusudanan I've gone to the script directory but am still getting the same error: 
rchase@USARRRCHASE7 /cygdrive/c/users/rchase/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/Scripts
$ python aws
C:\Users\rchase\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\python.exe: can't open file 'aws': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: @RyanChase when you list contents of Script dir do you see aws?

Comment: @maheshmadhusudanan ah, I figured it out!  So aws is not saved as a executable (.exe).  So if I `cd` to the Scripts location (where aws is saved), I have to type `python aws` specifically.   Alternatively, typing `./aws` also works since the `./` part says "look for the appropriate executable (i.e. python) to run this script.

Comment: @maheshmadhusudanan so now I have to use the whole file path - i.e.  `python /cygdrive/c/Users/rchase/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda2/Scripts/aws`.  When I do that it seems to work, but if I'm not in the directory, then running `python aws` doesn't work.  Further, running `aws` alone doesn't working without "python" in front.  My next challenge is how do I now run setup_p2.sh?  Where does this script need to be saved?

Comment: @RyanChase its bit tricky...my workaround was that I changed the setup_p2.sh file to prepend python whereever there is aws command

Comment: @maheshmadhusudanan Can you provide and example?  Or list the specifics on how I would go about doing that?  I feel that I'm close.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Basic problem is that the Windows installation of Python is in PATH and clashes with cygwin python (if/when you install it).

Most complete answer is from Wouter van Amsterdam above. But if like me you don't care for Windows python then just goto Windows "Add or remove programs" and uninstall the Python. Then install Python using `apt-cyg` on cygwin command line, then `pip` and then `awscli`.

If you have the Windows python and you install awscli (or any python package) on cygwin command line, then depending on your PATH and PYTHONPATH etc, you might still end up installing it into the Windows installation of Python. Which is what causes OP problem.