# No such file or directory error when configuring aws on cygwin awscli

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, cygwin

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rjRfW4JM2I
and I had gone through this [No such file or directory error when configuring aws on cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41464084/no-such-file-or-directory-error-when-configuring-aws-on-cygwin)

But still I am getting error after I 
do $ export $PATH = 'cat foo'

-bash: export:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/cygdrive/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/cygdrive/c/windows/system32:/cygdrive/c/windows:/cygdrive/c/windows/System32/Wbem:/cygdrive/c/windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/cygdrive/c/Program': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Files/TortoiseSVN/bin:/cygdrive/c/Program': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `(x86)/Windows': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Kits/10/Windows': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Toolkit:/cygdrive/c/Program': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Files/Microsoft': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Server/130/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Users/aman.dalmia/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python27:/cygdrive/c/Users/aman.dalmia/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python27/Scripts:/cygdrive/c/Program': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Files/PuTTY:/cygdrive/c/Program': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Files/Microsoft': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Server/120/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Files/nodejs:/cygdrive/c/Program': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Files/Git/cmd:/cygdrive/c/Program': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Files/Microsoft': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Server/Client': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `SDK/ODBC/110/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `(x86)/Microsoft': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Server/120/Tools/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Files/Microsoft': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Server/120/DTS/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `(x86)/Microsoft': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Server/120/Tools/Binn/ManagementStudio:/cygdrive/c/Program': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `(x86)/Microsoft': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Server/120/DTS/Binn:/cygdrive/c/Program': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `Files/TortoiseGit/bin:/cygdrive/c/Users/aman.dalmia/AppData/Roaming/npm:/cygdrive/d/Installs/Maven/bin:': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `D:/Tesseract-OCR:/cygdrive/c/Users/aman.dalmia/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python27/Scripts:/cygdrive/c/Users/aman.dalmia/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python27': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `cat foo': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: What is your question? For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You wrote

```
export $PATH = 'cat foo'
```

You need

```
export PATH=`cat foo`
```

With `$PATH` you are trying to export the value of PATH, but you want to export the PATH variable.
Around the `=` you have spaces. I like people who try to make their code readible, but with an assignment the spaces are forbidden.
Note that you must use spaces in `if [ "${somevar}" = "example" ]`
You are trying to execute `cat foo` in a subshell. You need backtics for that, not normal quotes.